# User entry array being filled with garbage

Tags: c, scanf

im trying to make this function work but the array keeps getting filled with trash. The cicle is running properly, I just cant seem to find the error.

```
int CargaArregloEnteros(int a[], int dim, int v);
void MostrarArreglo(int n[], int v);
int main()
{   int notas[100], validos=0;
    validos = CargaArregloEnteros(notas, 100, validos);
    printf("\nLos validos son %d\n", validos);
    MostrarArreglo(notas, validos);
    return 0;
}
int CargaArregloEnteros(int a[], int dim, int v)
{
    char opcion=0;
    while(v<dim && opcion !=27)
    {
        printf("\n Ingrese una nota a cargar ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("&d", &a[v]);
        printf("\n Presione ESCAPE para salir\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        opcion=getch();
        system("cls");
        v++;
    }
    return v;
}
void MostrarArreglo(int n[], int v)
{
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
    {
        printf("%d | ", n[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don;t do `fflush(stdin);`, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: You may want to translate the prompts to English.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
 scanf("&d", &a[v]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &a[v]);
```

so that it constitutes a valid conversion specifier syntax.

Also, a good lesson on why it's best to check the return value of `scanf()` and other library functions.

Comment: Must've been a typo, thank you very much!